# Ruby on Rails - after rails_s is entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.4

I am learning Ruby on Rails and still unfamilar with some of parts of the language.

I am trying to get a rails project to display on Firefox however as soon as I enter the command "rails s" I am presented with the following error:
[Rails S Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9G0q.jpg)  
The source code is :

C:\Sites\weeks_1_-_15\week_1\bookshop1a>rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/act
ive_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mingw32/
lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (
LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10
-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in`rescue in '
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10
-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in`require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in`each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in`each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6
/lib/bundler.rb:106:in`require'
        from C:/Sites/weeks_1_-_15/week_1/bookshop1a/config/application.rb:7:in
`<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in`require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in`tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in`require'
        from script/rails:6:in `'

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Please post code snippets instead of screenshots

Comment: @NickM Please see my edited post

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that SQLite is not installed or properly configured.
Try starting rails server after installing SQLite first.

Maybe this tutorial is helpful to get SQLite up and running:

http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/download-install-sqlite/